# powershell folder create and create robocopy files

Tags: powershell

Hi cant work out whats wrong here... i need this script to create a folder for the robocopy log, and then create the robocopy txt file. works fine, but it wont create the \log folder... help please?

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\x\y\z"
$destFolder   = "C:\x\y\zz"
{ 
{
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$DestFolder\Log" 
}
foreach ($folder in (Get-ChildItem  -Directory $sourceFolder)) {
    "robocopy `"$($sourceFolder)\$($folder)\zArchive\Data files to Nov 13`" `"$($destFolder)\$($folder)\folder`" /E /MOVE /DCOPY:T /log+:`"$DestFolder\Log\log.olog`"" | Out-File zArchiveMove.txt -Append
    "robocopy `"$($sourceFolder)\$($folder)\Data files to Nov 13`"     `"$($destFolder)\$($folder)\folder`" /E /MOVE /DCOPY:T /log+:`"$DestFolder\Log\log.olog`""     | Out-File zArchiveMove2.txt -Append
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is it written the way it is in terms of curly brackets? I can't say I know a lot about Powershell, but simply repeating your code in a test window has it echoing at me. So if I write:

```
{{new-item -itemtype Directory -Force -Path "$DestFolder\Log"}}
```

It'll echo. As will:

{new-item -itemtype Directory -Force -Path "$DestFolder\Log"}

If I ditch the curly brackets, it works.
So I would recommend you get rid of the curly brackets unless they're needed for something. If they're within a code block relating to a conditional statement, please replicate that here.

So:

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\x\y\z"
$destFolder   = "C:\x\y\zz"


New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$DestFolder\Log" 

foreach ($folder in (Get-ChildItem  -Directory $sourceFolder)) {
 "robocopy `"$($sourceFolder)\$($folder)\zArchive\Data files to Nov 13`" `"$($destFolder)\$($folder)\folder`" /E /MOVE /DCOPY:T /log+:`"$DestFolder\Log\log.olog`"" | Out-File zArchiveMove.txt -Append
 "robocopy `"$($sourceFolder)\$($folder)\Data files to Nov 13`"     `"$($destFolder)\$($folder)\folder`" /E /MOVE /DCOPY:T /log+:`"$DestFolder\Log\log.olog`""     | Out-File zArchiveMove2.txt -Append
}
```

Should work. Please test and report back. Also please consider indenting your initial code. I know Powershell users don't do it as often but when you're nesting code blocks its just so much easier to read.